# Java expects a semicolon, when there is clearly one

Tags: java

```
public class Machine{
   String machineType;
   public Machine(String s){ //Sets machineType to String s
      String getName();
   }
}
```

Why wont this compile? I keep getting a error, saying that its expecting a semicolon, but there is one!

Comment: Probably the following line is creating the problem?

Comment: An error like "expecting semicolon" means that the compiler was expecting a semicolon in a particular place.  The fact that you have one doesn't matter, if it's in the wrong place.  Many compilers are not good at generating helpful error messages.  You'll have to get used to it, and be thankful that you're not using GNU C++ which tends to give me several screenfuls of unhelpful error messages whenever I make one error.

Answer (score 3):

We cant call methods like this

```
 public Machine(String s){ //Sets machineType to String s
  String getName();    // Method
 }
```

Instead, assign it to a variable

```
 public Machine(String s){ //Sets machineType to String s
  String var = getName();    // assuming getName returns a string
 }
```

Even this would work

```
 public Machine(String s){ //Sets machineType to String s
   getName();    
 }
```

Comment: I believe he wants "machineType = s;" by the comment, but you answered the question!

Comment: `// assuming getName returns void` <- you should remove that. Otherwise great!

Comment: Yes that would work in all cases as well, but i was thinking about the ideal situation.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
 String getName();
```

Makes no sense. Either change it to this:

```
 String name = getName();
```

Or more likely you want:

```
public Machine(String s) {
    machineType = s;
}
```

But I don't know how you could intend that but get the code you got.

Comment: That's impossible, unless you put that code somewhere strange, such as not in the constructor. I have added in the lines to make a complete constructor. I thought that was obvious, but maybe it wasn't. Try it now as I've coded it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to call the method `getName()`
If that is the case you either have to do:

```
getName();
```

or

```
String name = getName();
```

Use the first if the method has no return type (void), and the second if it is a String.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can do like this,

```
 public void Machine(String s){ 
      getName();
}
```